# How to separate controller name with dash in Zend Framework?

Tags: zend-framework, controller

I'm just new to Zend and currently I'm trying to add a dash(-) to my controller name. It

look something like this **module/first-controller/action**. Please notice that is

**controller name not action name**. Can someone give me a solution to this problem? Thank you

very much in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The class name `FirstControllerController` becomes `first-controller` in the URL.

Okay, that's a bad example. If you want to have `user-address` in the URL and you create the controller with the `zf` command line tool you call it like that `zf create controller UserAddress` the actual class name of the controller is `UserAddressController` (and the file name is therefore `UserAddressController.php`).

So every *bump* in the CamelCase name will be separated by a hyphen in the URL. The same is true for action names (`getAddressAction()` -> `get-address`).

Comment: Oddly enough the view script must be separated by a dash instead of pageName, it should be page-name (for view script folders and files). Thanks for the easy to find answer :P!